# SQL bitwise query to pull multiple days of events, while obeying other "filters"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a query that will pull events from a DB based on a series of filters: baseId, title, age, and days it will occur.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM [Events]
WHERE BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 
AND (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) 
OR (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4)
```

Without the OR line, it pulls just fine. With the OR line, it no longer cares about the BaseId, Title, MinAge, and MaxAge columns. Well, it does, but only up to the point where the OR is... and then it pulls all that match after the OR (regardless of the previous AND statements).

How can I get the query to filter by each column, and then also by each FreqInterval I want? I may have more than just 2, 4... could have any combination of 1,2,4,8,16,32, or 64.

Or, is there a way to do a `AND (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 6) = 6)` using a SUM of the FreqInterval? I don't fully understand bitwise querying.

Comment: You could just put those `OR` inside the same condition. `AND ( (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) OR (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4) OR .... )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM [Events]
WHERE BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 
AND 
(
   (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) 
   OR (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4) 
)
```

OR has lower operator precedence than AND, you should put parenthesis around them. You can simplify it further:

```
   (FreqType = 8 
       AND ( (FreqInterval & 2) = 2 OR (FreqInterval & 4) = 4) )
   )
```

And as your suggestion, it's almost correct, here's the right one though:

```
 (FreqType = 8 
       AND (FreqInterval & 6) <> 0 )
```

By the way, another term for operator precedence is operator stickiness, if your original query is to be written explicitly, it is this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Events]
WHERE 
( 
  BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 
  AND (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) 
)

OR 

(FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4)
```

That's akin to `4 * 3 + 5`, multiplication has higher precedence than addition, so 3 sticks to 4 instead of 5, so the output is `17`. If your objective is to output `32`, you should explicitly stick 3 to 5, put a parenthesis around 3 and 5, i.e. `4 * (3 + 5)`

So on your query that uses OR, to make them stick together, put parenthesis around them.

Nonetheless, just like what you hinted, I like this better ツ

```
 (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 6) <> 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile to explain this, really helped.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with bitwise logic.  You just need to fix your `WHERE` clause to make the two bitwise comparisons part of the same evaluation set using parentheses:

```
...
AND (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2 OR 
                       FreqInterval & 4) = 4))
```

You also don't need to check `FreqType` twice so I simplified that bit for you.

`OR` means that any prior criteria can be ignored.  Putting this in the parentheses with the other bitwise check means ONE of them has to return true.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a priority issue. You're doing:

```
BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 AND (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) 
OR
(FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4)
```

Try to add an additional ()

```
WHERE BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 
AND ((FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) OR (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [Events]
WHERE BaseId = 574 AND Title LIKE '%occurs%' AND MinAge <= 5 AND MaxAge >= 5 
AND ((FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 2) = 2) 
OR (FreqType = 8 AND (FreqInterval & 4) = 4))
```